# Index not getting deleted in elasticsearch using delete API

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I created an index

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/tipindex/' -d '{
     "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1,
          }
     }
  }
}'
```

and then I associated a river with the index using the following command :

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/tipindex/_meta" -d '
{
"type": "mongodb",
"mongodb": {
    "host": "<machine-name>",
    "port": "27017",
    "db": "mydb",
    "collection": "tips"
},
"index": {
    "name": "tipindex",
    "type": "tips"
 }
}'
```

The index is properly created and all the documents are indexed. However, if I delete the index using :

```
curl -XDELETE '<machine-name>:9200/tipindex/'
```

It completes with `{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}`

ES log : [tipindex] deleting index

Now if I execute curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/tipindex/'

```
{"error":"IndexMissingException[[tipindex] missing]","status":404}
```

which means that index is deleted.

But if I restart elasticsearch the index is created again with 0 documents and no mapping.

If I recreate the index and associate a river, then no documents are indexed. ES log do not show any error as well.

Now my questions are :

- Why is the index not getting deleted ?
- When I recreate the index,why are the documents not getting indexed again?
- How can I delete an index forcefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to mongo river.

> Why is the index not getting deleted ?

It does recreate the index each time you restart the river if the index does not exist.

> When I recreate the index,why are the documents not getting indexed again?

I think that Mongo river store in `_river/tipindex` index the last fetch point. As you already run the river, something is remaining in it.
You can check all documents remaining in this index:

```
curl localhost:9200/_river/tipindex/_search?q=*
```

If you need to *restart* the river, the best option is to me to remove and recreate the river as you did before.

HTH

Comment: If I have deleted the index, how come it is getting re-created? Is there any way by which I can stop the river from creating this index. 
I have already mentioned that the total number of documents are zero after index is created automatically by the river on restart. 

How can I remove and recreate the river. AFAIK, i just deleted the index and it should automatically delete the attached river.

Comment: No. The deletion of index does not delete the river.

Comment: To answer to `how come it is getting re-created?`, see https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/river/mongodb/MongoDBRiver.java#L390

Comment: Don't know if this helps, I'll just leave this here. I had a similar problem with the jdbc river, I deleted the river and then the index, ES kept rebuilding the index and the river, I had modified the elasticsearch.yml config file, i set the work directory to /usr/local/elasticsearch-0.90.0/work (but the directory did not exist, and ES was working without create it - it didn't use it at all). Then I tried to comment that setting (using the default) and the deletion worked fine.